# Eclipse CDT clean fails on Windows: tries to run rm -rf

Tags: windows, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I am using Juno with CDT on Windows 7.
When I try to clean a project using the internal builder or make provided by MinGW, Eclipse runs the *X command 
    rm -rf
and the clean operation fails.

Log using external builder (mingw32-make) from the console:

```
18:08:07 **** Clean-only build of configuration Debug for project threads_example ****
mingw32-make clean 
rm -rf  ./main.o  ./main.d  threads_example
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, rm -rf ./main.o ./main.d threads_example, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.

mingw32-make: [clean] Error 2 (ignored)
' '

18:08:07 Build Finished (took 137ms)
```

Log using the internal builder:

```
10:39:35 **** Clean-only build of configuration Debug for project threads_example ****
rm -rf threads_example main.o main.d 
Cannot run program "rm": Launching failed

Error: Program "rm" not found in PATH
PATH=[C:\CS_powerpc\bin;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/bin/client;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java    /jre7/bin;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/lib/i386;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Microsoft Online Services;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Microsoft Online Services;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\OEM\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\OEM\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\OEM\12.0\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Roxio\OEM\AudioCore\;C:\siriusSDK\CS_i686\bin;c:\siriusSDK\CS_powerpc\bin;C:\siriusSDK\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin;C:\MinGW\bin;;C:\work\eclipse]


10:39:35 Build Finished (took 41ms)

10:39:35 **** Clean-only build of configuration Debug for project threads_example ****

10:39:35 Build Finished (took 46ms)
```

Comment: Looks like Eclipse + CDT needs UNIX-like commands to work as desired. I resolved installing on Windows  the GNU coreutils 5.3.0

Answer (score 5):

The best solution is to install **[GnuUtils/coreutils](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/files/coreutils/5.3.0/coreutils-5.3.0.exe/download)**  and add the installed directory (C:\ProgramFiles\GnuWin32\bin)to your windows path then restart eclipse.

Eclipse should execute rm-rf now...

If it still doesn't work, just restart Windows (to set path in windows memeory) and check your path again to be sure it has \GnuWin32\bin . Finally start eclipse.

Comment: CoreUtils for Windows provides not only rm but also a bunch of other GNU utilities for native Linux users on Windows system. Its a very good solution indeed.

Answer (score 4):

Turns out there's an attribute in the .cproject file xml the controls the clean command.

Look for the configuration tag, and set the `cleanCommand` attribute to what you want. I've set it to `rm -rf` and used gnuutils to support the command on windows.
You can change the command to whatever.

```
<configuration artifactExtension="so" artifactName="MyProject" ... cleanCommand="rm -rf" ...>
```

Comment: I created a Windows configuration in which (.cproject) I replaced the rm with del /S *.*.
Funny thing is that CDT console shows "Cannot run program 'del'..." but deletion works anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a workaround, that works good for me:
If you look in the managed make makefile, you can find a line "RM := ..."
After that line there is a line "-include ../makefile.defs" which does not exist in my case.

If you create this file, you can redefine the "RM := ..." macro to whatever you want.

For example:
RM := del

In this case, the automated build process will use your definition to delete files and folders and not the predefined definition of eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error because i had a typo in **MSYS_HOME** under **Project->properties->C/C++ Build->Environment**

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to install [Git for Windows](https://git-scm.com/download/win) and enable Unix-like commands for cmd.exe in the installation options. Then `rm -rf` will be supported.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to install Git for Windows and enable Unix-like commands for cmd.exe in the installation options. Then rm -rf will be supported.

[A simple solution is to install Git for Windows.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67NXr.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).