# Eclipse command "clean" for C++ project generates "cannot run program "del": launching failed" for Win8.1

Tags: eclipse, windows, windows-8.1, eclipse-cdt

I found [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=242649) reported 2008-07-30 and its status is still "NEW". As I can see from [this patch](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/attachment.cgi?id=221302&action=diff) Eclipse (Version: Luna Release (4.4.0) Build ID: 20140612-0600) trying to remove some files using "del" or `cmd /c del` -- neither are correct.

If Eclipse could ask for `-rm` command as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17964253/eclipse-cdt-clean-fails-on-windows-tries-to-run-rm-rf) I'd install any of UNIX-like command application as problem solution. But what should I do to add "del" command for my Win8?

I tried to take rm.exe from MinGW, rename it to del.exe and put to path. But then the error is "del: cannot lstat `src/test.o': No such file or directory". The same for rm.exe from cygwin64 gives no error but also does not delete o-files -- it was expected due to different syntax of rm and del command.