# Can I set the "clean" command in Eclipse Neon CDT without manually editing .cproject?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

It seems to be a common problem with Eclipse CDT on Windows that Eclipse uses the Windows "del" command to perform a "clean", while using Unix-style paths and rm options. The workaround, at least for the Juno release, is to force Eclipse to use the GnuUtils rm instead: [Editing .cproject to change the clean command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33040777/8383305)

I had the opposite problem - Eclipse insisted on running "del" in a project using the GNU toolchain and MinGW build tools, which did not work. Therefore, I edited .cproject to force the use of rm.

Is this the only way to do it, even in newer releases of Eclipse, e.g. Neon? I would expect that Eclipse has a built-in control for this setting, but I browsed through the project settings and through the online help without finding any.